# Unable to create a db table with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am learning how to use schema builder to create tables. I have got phpmyadmin running on 127.0.0.1:81/phpmyadmin. I created a db in phpmyadmin named testdb.

On my laravel app in app/config/database.php i have made changes to 'mysql' section as:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1:81',
        'database'  => 'testdb',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

On app/routes.php i wrote :

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

On app/controller/HomeController.php i wrote:

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    Schema::create('employee', function($emp_table){
        $emp_table->increments('id');
        $emp_table->string('name');
        $emp_table->integer('salary');
    });

    return View::make('hello');
}
```

Now i am getting a 'Something went wrong' message when reloading localhost:8000. It should be creating the table 'employee' with fields 'id', 'name' and 'salary'. The  'app/storage/logs/laravel.log' says:

```
[2015-01-14 06:09:49] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in C:\wamp\www\stylop-dev\bootstrap\compiled.php:9301
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Please help, i am stuck fixing this error and have hit a dead end :(

Comment: Please add an answer to your question by using the **Answer Your Question** button on the bottom left of this page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess i figured out why i was getting the error. I was using 127.0.0.1:81 so i changed it back to the default port 80.

Now it works